# spring cloud zuul server : very high latency value

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I have an **edge zuul server service** which route requests to **downstream services**.

I load test this architecture with 400 thread concurrently

in the **downstream service** the total latency is only **one second**.
using a pre and post zuul filters on **edge server**, I managed to calculate latency to be about  **7.5 seconds** on average which is approximately the same figure I get from hystrix.stream endpoint enabled on my **edge zuul server**

> {  
>    "type":"HystrixCommand",
>    "name":"authenticate",
>    "group":"RibbonCommand",
>    "currentTime":1492879164747,
>    "isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,
>    "errorPercentage":0,
>    "errorCount":0,
>    "requestCount":500,
>    "rollingCountBadRequests":0,
>    "rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,
>    "rollingCountEmit":0,
>    "rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,
>    "rollingCountFailure":0,
>    "rollingCountFallbackEmit":0,
>    "rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,
>    "rollingCountFallbackMissing":0,
>    "rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,
>    "rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,
>    "rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,
>    "rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,
>    "rollingCountShortCircuited":0,
>    "rollingCountSuccess":492,
>    "rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,
>    "rollingCountTimeout":0,
>    "currentConcurrentExecutionCount":397,
>    "rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount":399,
>    "latencyExecute_mean":7552,
>    "latencyExecute":{  
>       "0":1003,
>       "25":8131,
>       "50":8359,
>       "75":8543,
>       "90":9095,
>       "95":10495,
>       "99":12311,
>       "99.5":12311,
>       "100":19551
>    },
>    **"latencyTotal_mean":7552**,
>    "latencyTotal":{  
>       "0":1003,
>       "25":8131,
>       "50":8359,
>       "75":8543,
>       "90":9095,
>       "95":10495,
>       "99":12311,
>       "99.5":12311,
>       "100":19551
>    },
>    "propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,
>    "propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,
>    "propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,
>    "propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,
>    "propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,
>    "propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,
>    "propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"SEMAPHORE",
>    "propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":200000,
>    "propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds":200000,
>    "propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,
>    "propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,
>    "propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":5000,
>    "propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,
>    "propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,
>    "propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,
>    "propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,
>    "reportingHosts":1,
>    "threadPool":"RibbonCommand"
> }

given that both the **edge server** and the **downstream service** is on the same internal network and given those properties values

> server.tomcat.max-threads=5000
>
> zuul.host.max-per-route-connections=5000
>
> zuul.host.max-total-connections=10000
>
> ## downstream service name : authenticate
>
> zuul.eureka.authenticate.semaphore.maxSemaphores=5000

I set the property server.tomcat.max-threads=5000 in both the **edge server and the downstream service**

Why the latency is so high like that in the **edge server**? how can eliminate it or how can I trace where the latency occurs?

I use spring boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE to build both the **edge server and the downstream service**

Comment: Which version of spring cloud are you using ?

Comment: Brixton.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem could be caused by maxTotalConnection and maxPerRoutConnections. If you are using zuul with ribbonRoutingFilter, please try to define the below properties.

```
authenticate:
  ribbon:
    MaxTotalHttpConnections: 5000
    MaxHttpConnectionsPerHost: 10000
    MaxTotalConnections: 5000  # just for using apache http client in camden
    MaxConnectionsPerHost: 10000 # just for using apache http client in camden
```

The current releases (brixton, camden, dalston) seem to have small bug about these properties. Unlike the documentation, zuul.host.max-per-route-connections, zuul.host.max-total-connections don't affect the actual configuration. Instead, we should define ribbon configuration directlt like above.

Comment: the property "propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":5000 already has the right value according hystrix.stream output.

Comment: I find out that the issue is related to our network setup..and the netwok team is in charge now...thnx for your support.